# How to remove character using javascript?

Tags: javascript

How do I remove the `,` after `Cite:` using javascript?

```
<div id="mydiv">
  <div>
    ::before
    <div>
      <blockquote>
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
        <cite>
          ::before
          "Cite:,    "
          <a href=""></a>
        </cite>
      </blockquote>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You may well write some code to find the text and modify it. What have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a general sense, removing a comma from a string is easy with a regular expression [`.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

```
someString = someString.replace(/Cite:,/,"Cite:");
```

You can apply that to the content of an HTML element as follows:

```js
var cite = document.querySelector("#mydiv cite");
cite.innerHTML = cite.innerHTML.replace(/Cite:,/,"Cite:");
```

```html
<div id="mydiv">
  <div>
    ::before
    <div>
      <blockquote>
        <p></p><p></p><p></p>
        <cite>
          ::before
          "Cite:,    "
          <a href=""></a>
        </cite>
      </blockquote>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

...but note that it will recreate all child elements of the cite element, including the anchor, which would remove any event listeners that had been bound to the anchor.

Answer (score 1):

I removed what i think you copy-paste from the html source code like `::before` but you can replace the content of an element using jquery

```js
$('cite')[0]
  .innerHTML = $('cite')[0]
    .innerHTML
    .trim()
    .replace(',', '');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mydiv">
  <div>
    <div>
      <blockquote>
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
        <cite>
          "Cite:,    "
          <a href="">link</a>
        </cite>
      </blockquote>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wouldn't this convert the anchor element to plain text? (Not that it would matter with an empty anchor with no href, but presumably the OP might like to include a functional anchor at some point.)

Comment: @nnnnnn you made a valid point .. answer has been edited and i added the link in the snippet to demonstrate

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using the `innerHTML` property of the `<cite>`, it is better to change only the contents of the text node containing the `"Cite:,` text. In this instance, we know that text node will be the `firstChild` of the `<cite>`.  In more complex HTML, it might be more appropriate to go searching for the appropriate text node under the `<cite>`.

The following code will change only the text. It will not disturb the anchor, `<a>`.  It will leave functional any listeners which might be on that node (or any other child node of the `<cite>`, if the HTML is actually more complex). [Note: this code is based on what [nnnnnn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/615754/nnnnnn) provided in an [answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39071035/3773011).]

```js
var cite = document.querySelector("#mydiv cite");
//In this instance, we know the text we want to modify will be in the text node
//   which is the firstChild of the <cite>.
cite.firstChild.textContent = cite.firstChild.textContent.replace(/Cite:,/,"Cite:");
```

```html
<div id="mydiv">
  <div>
    ::before
    <div>
      <blockquote>
        <p></p><p></p><p></p>
        <cite>
          ::before
          "Cite:,    "
          <a href=""></a>
        </cite>
      </blockquote>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```